# What version of iWork can I use with Snow Leopard Ver 10.6.8?

Tags: snow-leopard

I have tried to use iWork 09 but my machine is only Core duo and not Core 2 Duo so will not load.

Comment: What happens when you try to load it?

Answer (score 1):

It should run in your machine, as it is stated under Apple's [iWork: System Requirements](http://support.apple.com/kb/SP676?viewlocale=en_US) that **iWork '09** requires an **Intel processor** ( not a Core2Duo ) and **Mac OS X v10.5.6 or later**.

Here's all of the requirements:

> - A Mac with an Intel, PowerPC G5, or PowerPC G4 (500MHz or faster)    processor
> - 512MB of RAM; 1GB recommended
> - Approximately 1.2GB of available disk space
> - 32MB of video memory
> - Mac OS X v10.4.11 or **Mac OS X v10.5.6 or later**
> - QuickTime 7.5.5 or later
> - DVD drive required to install
> - Some features may require Internet access; additional fees and terms    apply